# Full Width Slider - Cross fade transition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a full width banner which I would like to fade in and out into different images. It does what is it supposed to do but my issue is the white background that displays during the fade - so i am looking for a cross fade.. but not to sure how to go about it.

My HTML is like so

```
<div id="backgroundimg">
  <div class="row copy limitedwidth extra-pad">
    <h1> Stay somewhere amazing </h1>
    <h1> this summer </h1>
    <p class="lrgfont hidden-xs">From city centre boutique to beach side mill, and arctic cabin to honeymoon suite. Discover our range of unique, friendly and affordable places to stay and you’ll never look at budget accommodation in the same way again! </p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

my CSS is like so

```
   #backgroundimg { background-image: url('/sites/default/files/Pwll_Deri_landing.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 66%; border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA6A6; min-height: 295px; }
.image-0 { background-image: url('/sites/default/files/Pwll_Deri_landing.jpg') !important; background-position: 50% 66% !important; }
.image-1 { background-image: url('/sites/default/files/seaside-large.jpg') !important; background-position: 50% 66% !important; }
.image-2 { background-image: url('/sites/default/files/london-large.jpg') !important; background-position: 50% 66% !important; }
```

and my JS below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seconds = 5000;
  var step = 0;
  var limit = 3;

  $("#backgroundimg").addClass("image-"+step).fadeIn(500);

  setInterval(function(){
    $("#backgroundimg").fadeOut(500,function(){
       $(this).removeClass("image-"+step);
       step = (step > limit) ? 0 : step + 1;
      $("#backgroundimg").addClass("image-"+step).fadeIn(500);
    });
  },seconds);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want cross fade out effect, then you should try to use `css transitions`, they are more convenient to use. Heres simple `gallery` function, which is just setting `active` class to images, and animation is on `css`:

```js
function initGallery(el) {
  var total = $('img', el).length,
    current = 0;

  return function animate(dur) {
    $('img', el).eq(current)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');

    current++;

    if (current == total) {
      current = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(animate, dur || 2000)
  }
}

initGallery('.gallery')(4000);
```

```css
.gallery {
  width: 300px;  
  position: relative;
}

.gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.gallery img.active {
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="//c5.staticflickr.com/8/7619/26712346812_a6f1def27d_b.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="//c5.staticflickr.com/8/7342/26205959324_729113fa7a_h.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="//c6.staticflickr.com/8/7331/26206092373_90604c520b_b.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```